# Server accessing wrong storage folder laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, server

I just uploaded my website to a live server and all is working well except I pulled a rookie mistake and I'm using my images folder to store all my users / files etc...

How would I fix this so I can use `$userDir = public_path().'/images/users/'`?

If I remove `public_path()` It grabs the correct images and creates the directory in the images folder of my website.

If I leave `public_path()` it creates a new public/images/users folder in my laravel app folder.

- I uploaded all my public files into the `pulic_html folder`
- All my laravel app files are a folder back. IE: `../../myappfolder/public_html`

Could I change config/filesystems.php

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

To this:

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'), ---> Not sure what to change here?
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/images', ---> Change to images..?
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Comment: did u find solution?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski not the solution I wanted... I had to go through all my controllers and remove `public_path()` that works, but now I'm battling another issue `mkdir(): Permission denied ` using `File::makeDirectory($myImageFolder, 0755, true)` Ahh so much fun =)